# Async OnCreate Error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi \I keep getting an error for my Async onCreate. 
This is the code, and the logcat trace. Any feedback appreciated.
The splash screen runs then the app stops once it starts the homescreen

```
public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {
```

Comment: You should not interact with Any UI components in Asynctask doInBackground() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to manipulate views in **doInBackground** of your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: so do i just remove the uisettings and camera settings for the mapfragment to postExecute? Do i leave the marker and fragment in the Async?

Comment: yes, move this to `onPostExecute` (if you want it do be executed after async thread is done) or `onPreExecute` (to execute it before the thread starts)

Comment: Ive moved them but im still getting same error?? Il upload updated code

Comment: Move the `MapFragment` and `Maker` part too because it is also related to views